# Applications lost permissions after flashing Marshmallow

Tags: rom-flashing, permissions, 6.0-marshmallow

I upgraded my Nexus 5 from Android 6 preview 3 to the 6.0 final version by manualy flashing image files from google factory image.
All my applications lost permissions and crashing. I am unable to give permissions through settings too. The only solution I found so far is to reinstall applications. However I don't want to reinstall all of them for obvious reasons.

Please advise how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flashing factory image solved the issue.
https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images

Answer (score 1):

For me the [boot.img modification by Chainfire](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/supersu/wip-android-6-0-marshmellow-t3219344) worked partially: device seems to be rooted (with supersu 2.51 beta), but twrp asks for password and cannot mount anything (I've posted [a question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/125361/56944) about the latter). In particular I could not install supersu via adb sideload from recovery, as Chainfire recommends. Rather I just installed apk from system (using simple explorer).

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify if this answer solve OP's problem? (particularly, about restoring apps permissions). I don't see if OP has any issue with flashing, and I didn't have this issue after flashing, so I'd like to know if flashing & rooting will help to solve OP's problem.

Comment: @AndrewT. I've posted this because of the comment to Andi's answer - Sergey asks for a working root which is required for that answer to work. In fact I believe the source of OP's problems is that Marshmallow blocks root access (among other things).

Comment: Thanks @მამუკაჯიბლაძე. I managed to root with the guide. TB reports errors though during restore, so I am not sure if the solution works.

Comment: @Sergey As I discovered today (see [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/125540/56944) to my own question), Chainfire's instructions do not mention one important step: after booting into recovery, one must wipe data. Did you do this?

Comment: (having your backup at safe place of course; I am just restoring playstore apps from my Google account and have apk files of the rest on pc)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე That wiping seems to be related to forceencrypt on Nexus 6, 9 and newer devices. Not relevant to Nexus 5

Comment: @Sergey I don't know that much but there might be some other things besides forceencrypt, like `ro.debuggable` or `ro.adb.secure`...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me the following helped (root needed):

- backup the app with Titanium Backup (TB); its an app available in PlayStore
- restore it immediatly with TB
- done (no uninstall needed; app data wont be affected)

Comment: Can you recommend a working root for 6.0?