# TWRP 2.8.7.0 asks for password on Marshmallow (Nexus 9), cannot mount anything

Tags: twrp, 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-9

After flashing TWRP and booting it (situation described in title), TWRP asks for password. When I bypass it, TWRP cannot mount anything. When I reboot to system, it is stuck at the startup animation forever. Only can boot when I reflash stock recovery. Actually I have to reflash system too, it cannot boot otherwise.

I also tried [boot.img replacement by Chainfire](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/supersu/wip-android-6-0-marshmellow-t3219344), result is exactly the same.

Has anybody successfully rooted Android 6 at all? What was the procedure?

**Update**
Just installed apk for supersu 2.51 (beta) and it seems to work - at least adb now goes root (could not before). However twrp still asks for password and cannot mount anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked for me like this:

1. Boot into Fastboot
2. Flash [Chainfire's WIP boot.img](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/supersu/wip-android-6-0-marshmellow-t3219344)
3. Flash [TWRP](https://dl.twrp.me/flounder/)
4. Copy latest [SuperSU BETA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/supersu/2014-09-02-supersu-v2-05-t2868133) onto a USB stick
5. Use an OTG adapter to connect that USB stick to your Nexus 9
6. Boot into TWRP
7. Tap "Cancel" at the password prompt
8. Mount the USB stick
9. Install the `SuperSU.zip` from USB
10. Reboot

I didn't have to install stock recovery or anything else. It booted up just fine with all data still there.

Comment: Sounds much better! So you do not need to wipe data?

Comment: No, you only have to wipe if you want to disable encryption. But for rooting only, you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Even I went into the same problem but finally I fixed it.

The reason why your phone gets stuck up on the start page is because android phones with lollipop and above version needs to unlock the boot loader to gain the privileges. This was implemented by google for the purpose of factory reset protection.

To do so you need to enable the **[OEM Unlocking](http://android.wonderhowto.com/news/psa-enable-hidden-setting-before-modding-anything-android-0167840/)** check box in Developer Options.

This is what I did and i finally rooted my device using TWRP recovery. If it doesn't work try installing the latest version of SuperSu.

Comment: In my case that was not the reason since my device was unlocked when this happened. On the bootloader screen this is explicitly declared.